# how to load the fuzzy effect placeholder for one picture before loading it from severs?

Tags: ios, swift

Fuzzy before loading, When got request successfully, it starts to load the image...[image]
My question is how to accomplish the mode don't depend on the other library
Here thank you in advance…….

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using YYWebImage CocoaPod to do this.

Here is my code

```
var url = "http://github.com/logo.png"
myImageView.yy_setImageWithURL(NSURL.init(string: url), options: YYWebImageOptions.SetImageWithFadeAnimation)
```

Please refer to this link. You will find a lot of things to do with image loading..
https://cocoapods.org/pods/YYWebImage

Comment: I know this third-party library ,the author is from my Chinese……Perhpas it’s a solution presently….Thank you so much….